# Symlink to source directory within every build subdirectory with autotools

Tags: autotools

Let's assume this project hierarchy:

```
root
|-src
| |-proj1
| |-proj2
| | |-src
| | | |-nested
|-build
```

Using GNU autotools and relying on recursive make, configuring and making the project hierarchy in the `build` directory is no problem with:

`root$ cd src && autoreconf -i && cd ../build && ../src/configure --options && make`

Now, since this creates a mirror of the `src` hierarchy in `build`, I'd like to have a symlink to the corresponding `src` subdir in every single subdir of `build`, like this:

```
root
|-src
| |-proj1
| |-proj2
| | |-src
| | | |-nested
|-build
| |-proj1
| | |-_src -> root/src/proj1
| |-proj2
| | |-_src -> root/src/proj2
| | |-src
| | | |-_src -> root/src/proj2/src
| | | |-nested
| | | | |-_src -> root/src/proj2/src/nested
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? If `$srcdir`, `$top_srcdir`, etc., are used correctly, the generated Makefiles should reference the source directories anyway.

Comment: Everything *is* generated correctly, I need those for my own use.

Comment: Use a `-local` or `-hook` [target](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending.html).

Comment: @BrettHale The way I understand it, I'd need to modify every Makefile.am to include a rule for this. Is there a way to define such a rule only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have been somewhat unspecific about what I'm going to do with the symlinks I asked for, so this solution wasn't very obvious. I simply wanted to access the source files, from within the build-dirs, during debugging, with as little typing as possible. Since then, I figured that an alias instead of many symlinks would do the job just as well:

```
$ less `s`/file.cc
```

where `s` is an alias defined as

```
alias s='pwd | sed -e "s|build|src|"'
```